# Using highcharts directive in angularjs

Tags: highcharts, angularjs-directive

using this jsfiddle:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/pablojim/Hjdnw/
```

I want to do the following:

make it a pie (easy), And now i want instead of all those "slices" something like:

```
  $scope.chartConfig = {
        options: {
            chart: {
                type: 'pie'
            }
        },
        series: **[{
            name: 'Jane',
            data: [1]
        }, {
            name: 'John',
            data: [5]
        }]**,
        title: {
            text: 'Hello'
        },

        loading: false
    }
```

And that doesn't work as i thought it will, anyone can elaborate why? a working js fiddle will be much appreciated!

Comment: What is it you want? Multiple pies, or slices with names?

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Hjdnw/657/ ? Or like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Hjdnw/658/ ?